# how to pass two connection string as one

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to pass two connection in single query .i have two database i have to update both databases at same time both have same structure and table secondary database is the backup one in below code i have made two connection but unable to pass both at single query

```
OracleConnection orc = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["delora"].ConnectionString);
OracleConnection orc2 = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["delora2"].ConnectionString);

using (OracleCommand orccmd = new OracleCommand("update tick set status='1' where id='" + id + "'", orc))
```

Comment: You will have to create 2 separate commands.

Comment: That is not possible. You could use a transaction so you can roll back if the 2nd update fails but you will still have 2 OracleCommand instances, 1 per database.

Comment: you might want to prefer replication over handling the redundant database yourself...

Comment: You could also take advantage of Oracle Triggers and Packages

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you want to connect 2 database you need to create 1 more command. Or when your object works is finished abort it and initilaze new connection to your object.